# Umbraco adds extra slash to beginning of page URL

Tags: umbraco7

Umbraco 7.12.4

Recently I renamed a node in Umbraco. It used to be called "Projects". I want it to be called "My Projects". After renaming it, no matter whether I put the name back to the original value or set an entirely new value, the following occurs:

- Change page name
- Click on properties. The Url appears correct, without an extra /
- Access the website. The website works correctly
- Access the website AGAIN. This page now redirects to http://my-projects and fails.
- Click on properties. The Url now appears as in the image below.

I have checked routes. Cleared URL redirects. Emptied recycle bin. Tried page names that have never existed before.

Any ideas? I am pulling my hair out. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is your hostname set to, if anything? Also maybe check if this node in particular has a hostname set by mistake? Does the website have any custom content finders that may be bonking out somehow?

Comment: I selected my root content node in the backoffice, clicked the "..." symbol, then selected "Do Something Else". Under the Culture and Hostnames option I discovered that my hostname was not set. After setting it to match my actual hostname, the problem has been resolved. If you wish to create an answer, I will mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to a missing host name - look at comments :-)